# Select and update the results SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Table name emp contains the below details

```
|ID     |EmpID  |Date         |
|6248   |56     |15/5/18 9:10 | 
|8743   |87     |14/5/18 10:00|
|7656   |78     |15/5/18 13:56|
```

In the same table emp, I got three new ID's

```
ID
5643
5678
8954
```

I want to update the table for the new ids with the same EmpID and Date.

Like this

```
|ID     |EmpID  |Date         |
|5643   |56     |15/5/18 9:10 |
|5678   |87     |14/5/18 10:00|
|8954   |78     |15/5/18 13:56|
```

Is it possible to do that in a single query to select and update the details?

I need to update more than 2000+ entries and I will be creating a script do the same but before that, I need to find the query to do the same.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What is the relationship between the three original records, and the three new records which you want to insert/update?

Comment: It is just three new records(id) in the same table. I want to match empID and date with the new ID

Comment: The new data you showed doesn't have any `empID` values.  Where are those values?

Comment: Is the new data (EmpID and Date) stored in a other table?

Comment: New data is stored in the same table. Let me summarise .I want to select empID,date from emp where id in() and update set empID={},date ={} from emp . I would like to do it in same statement

Comment: What I ment to ask was: Where do you get the new data from. Is it stored somewhere in the database as well?

Comment: Yes. It is stored in the database . But cureently empID and Date is null for the new entries

Comment: What Tim and I mean to ask. The data you are going to insert (EmpID and Date). Where do you have it now? Is it stored somewhere in a other table or is it currently not yet in the database? :) To get it all clear. Could you provide the tablenames and exampledata of the tables if there are 2 tables?

Comment: This is basically impossible

Comment: Yes.That data is in the same table in the database. Can you please see the question ? In that, I have mentioned the details. I am not able to copy paste it here.Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is via conditional updating.

```
UPDATE table
   SET column1 = CASE id 
                      WHEN '1' THEN 'abc' 
                      WHEN '2' THEN 'bcd' 
                      ELSE column1
                      END
WHERE id IN('1', '2');
```

The query aboves updates column1 for the rows with id 1 and 2 to abc and bcd.